# Organizing a MultiIndex DataFrame after set_index

Tags: python, pandas, structure, multi-index

I have data stored in a SQL database. When I call this data, it gets back to me as a DataFrame (I am using pandas).

I then set_index to organized it as a MultiIndex level DataFrame.

```
data.set_index(['colname1', 'colname2', 'colname3'],inplace=True)
```

However, my Data isn't shaped in a fully organized way. Meaning I would like this data to be stored this way:

How I would like it to be:

[image]

And currently it's returned this way, in a non organized way:

[image]

Comment: did you try `df = df.sort_index()`?

Comment: Works perfectly! Sometimes it easier than we thought. Thanks

Comment: Okay, great. Just wanted to confirm, since this appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed, I am new in pandas, sometimes I don't know exactly how to check for existing subjects. But thanks for the warning. Will spend more time looking next time.